# How to Resize Controls in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, viewbox

I am working on a Silverlight application and my problem is like this: I have a `StackPanel`
and inside the stackpanel I have a `ViewBox`. Inside the viewbox I am adding images and rotating them 90 and/or -90 degrees.

When rotated, my images go out of the viewbox. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `(viewbox).UpdateLayout` or `(viewbox).InvalidateArrange` or `(viewbox).InvalidateMeasure` work at all?

Comment: Is it possible that you are rotaing the image somewhere else than in the middle of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something other than StackPanel, it doesn't resize.

Answer (score 0):

There's a control in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) that addresses this problem called the `LayoutTransformer`. It ensures that when you change the transform, the bounds of the control are within the `LayoutTransformer` bounds.

You can see this at work in the [Silverlight Toolkit demo](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html). Just scroll down the tree on the left to the Layout section.